# How to use a class as a type in a variable with typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, oop

I'm bit confused in how to use OOP in typescript.

I'm used to do it with PHP.

1 - Can I use a class as a type without having to fill all attributes values?

2 - Do I really need to create an interface to create class attributes and use it as type in some function?

**For example, this is my class:**

```
class User {
  protected id: number;
  protected name: string;
  protected age?: Date;
  
  constructor(id: number, name: string, age: Date) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  
  getId() return this.id;

  getName() return this.name;
  setName(value: string) this.name = value;

  getAge() return this.age;
  setAge(value: Date) this.age = value;
}
```

**And this is my service function:**

```
const test = () => {
  const user = new User({id: 1, name: 'Rick' });
}
```

I tried many ways and all returned some error, this is the main one.

```
Type '{ id: string; name: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'User': getId, getName, setName
```

I know I can do this with interface, but I'm looking for a way to do this without interfaces, if it's possible.

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't compile as is--your constructor takes three separate arguments, and you're trying to pass in a single object-type argument. JS/TS doesn't have keyword arguments like some other languages, try passing in the ID, name, and age all separately.

Comment: @y2bd yes, it was just an example. Thanks for the help, I saw my mistake! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this...

```
class User {
    protected id: number;
    protected name: string;
    protected age?: Date;

    constructor({id, name, age }: { id: number, name: string, age?: Date }) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
}

const user1 = new User({id: 1, name: 'Rick' });
const user2 = new User({id: 1, name: 'Rick', age: undefined });
const user3 = new User({id: 1, name: 'Rick', age: new Date() });

// const user4= new User({id: 1, name: 'Rick', age: new Date(), addProp: [] }); // <== Error
```

Typescript documentation does have a section on [Parameter Destructuring](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#parameter-destructuring)

If we find it too verbose, we can define a `type alias` for the type of parameters of the constructor, like ...

```
type UserParams = { id: number, name: string, age?: Date };

class User {
    protected id: number;
    protected name: string;
    protected age?: Date;

    constructor({id, name, age }: UserParams) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
}

const user1 = new User({id: 1, name: 'Rick' });
const user2 = new User({id: 1, name: 'Rick', age: undefined });
const user3 = new User({id: 1, name: 'Rick', age: new Date() });

// const user4= new User({id: 1, name: 'Rick', age: new Date(), addProp: [] }); // <== Error
```

We could have used the class `User` as a type in the constructor parameter, but the problem is that all properties of class `User` are marked `protected` and passing-in arguments with those names of the properties will error out. However, if we can make these properties `public`, we should be able to achieve what we want...

```
class User {
    id: number;   // <== protected modifier gone
    name: string; // <== protected modifier gone
    age?: Date;   // <== protected modifier gone

    constructor({ id, name, age }: User) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
}

const user1 = new User({ id: 1, name: 'Rick' });
const user2 = new User({ id: 1, name: 'Rick', age: undefined });
const user3 = new User({ id: 1, name: 'Rick', age: new Date() });

// const user4 = new User({ id: 1, name: 'Rick', age: new Date(), addProp: [] }); // <== Error
```

Answer (score 2):

You can reduce your implementation to one line:

```js
class User {
    constructor(protected id: number, protected name: string, protected age?: Date) { }
}

// {
//     "id": 1,
//     "name": "2",
//     "age": undefined
// }
const result = new User(1, '2') // ok
```

[PLayground](https://tsplay.dev/WoGypW)